# how can I give the data source for OLEDB during the run time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an excel template file saved in web server folder.
During the run time I am giving the data source using the variable(dunsno) and date
but it throws an error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 3.

**I just want to know how to write the connection string in the server side**

I have done this:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   string connStr = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='Server.MapPath(~/Profile/ +     "Tempfile" + dunsno + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + ".xls");Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/temp/"));
                        var fileList = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
                        string newFileName = Server.MapPath("~/Profile/" + "Tempfile" + dunsno + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + ".xls");
                        foreach (FileInfo fleInfo in fileList)
                        {
                            fleInfo.CopyTo(newFileName, true);
                        }

                        OleDbConnection MyConnection;
                        OleDbCommand MyCommand = new OleDbCommand();
                        MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(connStr);

                        MyConnection.Open();
                        MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
                        string sql = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (id,name) values('3','c')";
                        MyCommand.CommandText = sql;
                        MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MyConnection.Close();

  }
```

Some more VBA point to have this clarity :

```
Sub GrabLastNames()

    'dimension (set aside memory for) our variables
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim ele As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim e As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim h As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim t As HTMLTable
    Dim s As String
   Dim x, y, z
   Dim c As Integer
   Dim post As Object, Elem As Object

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True


   i = 0
    objIE.Navigate "http://apps.who.int/immunization_monitoring/globalsummary/countries?countrycriteria%5Bcountry%5D%5B%5D=ALB&commit=OK"



     Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
  Set post = objIE.Document.getElementById("countrycriteria_country")

   For Each Elem In post.getElementsByTagName("option")
   c = c + 1
   If c = 6 Then Exit For
     Elem.Selected = True
     objIE.Document.getElementById("countrycriteria_country").Focus
     objIE.Document.getElementById("countrycriteria_country").FireEvent ("onchange")
     Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    For Each ele In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")            '.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr")
      s = LCase(Trim(ele.innerText))
      If InStr(s, "immunization schedule") Or InStr(s, "percentage target population vaccinated by antigen") Then
        For Each e In ele.Rows
          i = i + 1
          j = 3

         ' Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value = Elem.Value
           For Each h In e.Cells
           j = j + 1
            Sheet1.Cells(i, j).Value = h.innerText
           Next h
        Next e
      End If

    Next ele

    Next Elem

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub

Sub Select_Item()
    Dim post As Object, Elem As Object

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://apps.who.int/immunization_monitoring/globalsummary/countries?countrycriteria%5Bcountry%5D%5B%5D=ALB&commit=OK"  ''stored the html elements within "element.html" file to test it locally
       While .Busy = True Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set post = .Document.getElementById("countrycriteria_country")

       For Each Elem In post.getElementsByTagName("option")
            If Elem.Value = "BHS" Then Elem.Selected = True: Exit For

          '  i = i + 1
          '  If i = 4 Then Exit For
        Next Elem
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        .Document.getElementById("countrycriteria_country").Focus
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
      '.Document.getElementById("countrycriteria_country").Change
      .Document.getElementById("countrycriteria_country").FireEvent ("onchange")
    End With

End Sub

   ' Loop vba========
    '     Elem.Selected = True
    '     objIE.Document.getElementById("countrycriteria_country").Focus
    '     objIE.Document.getElementById("countrycriteria_country").FireEvent ("onchange")
    '     Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Sub getCoverage()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Sheet1.Cells.Clear
        'dimension (set aside memory for) our variables
        Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
        Dim ele As HTMLLinkElement
        Dim e As HTMLLinkElement
        Dim h As HTMLLinkElement
        Dim t As HTMLTable
        Dim s As String
       Dim x, y, z
       Dim con(1000)
       Dim c As Integer
       Dim post As Object, Elem As Object
       Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String, s4 As String

        Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
        objIE.Visible = True
    ' Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        s1 = LCase(shtweb.Range("d5").Value)
        s2 = LCase(shtweb.Range("e5").Value)
        s3 = LCase(shtweb.Range("f5").Value)
        s4 = LCase(shtweb.Range("g5").Value)

        s2 = IIf(s2 = "", "fsdfswew", s2)
        s3 = IIf(s3 = "", "fsdfswew", s3)
        s4 = IIf(s4 = "", "fsdfswew", s4)

       i = 0
        objIE.Navigate "http://apps.who.int/immunization_monitoring/globalsummary/countries?countrycriteria%5Bcountry%5D%5B%5D=ALB&commit=OK"

         Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
      Set post = objIE.Document.getElementById("countrycriteria_country")

       For Each Elem In post.getElementsByTagName("option")
           con(c) = Elem.Value
           c = c + 1
        Next Elem
        'objIE.

         For k = 0 To c
         If con(k) = "" Then Exit For
          objIE.Navigate "http://apps.who.int/immunization_monitoring/globalsummary/countries?countrycriteria%5Bcountry%5D%5B%5D=" & con(k) & "&commit=OK"

         Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        For Each ele In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")            '.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr")
          s = LCase(Trim(ele.innerText))
          If InStr(s, s1) Or InStr(s, s2) Or InStr(s, s3) Or InStr(s, s4) Then
            For Each e In ele.Rows
              i = i + 1
              j = 3

              Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value = con(k)
               For Each h In e.Cells
               j = j + 1
               If Left(h.innerText, 1) = "=" Then
                Sheet1.Cells(i, j).Value = "'" & h.innerText
               Else
                Sheet1.Cells(i, j).Value = h.innerText
               End If
               Next h
            Next e
          End If

        Next ele
        Next k


        ActiveWorkbook.Save
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: I googled your error, and there were so many results.

Answer (score 0):

use `Path.Combine` and a `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` to create a valid connection-string:

```
var conString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}"
                         , Path.Combine(dir, "nik.mdb"));
var conBuilder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(conString);
using (var con = new OleDbConnection(conBuilder.ConnectionString))
{
// ...
}
```

Maybe you have white-spaces in the connection string.